# "org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException" Error displayed in the code

Tags: java, selenium, pom.xml, browser-automation

I am unable to find what is the cause of the error "org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException" in my code, Please help me find and understand the cause much better. Firstly I would like to explain my code, It is a simple code where I go to a website click on "Sign In" link and then click on a text "Email" text field for registration purpose. I have used Page Factory in this code.

```
I have 3 files.
- Base file (Before and After methods) 
- Registration File (Object repository and methods)
- Registration_Testcase File (Calling the methods)

Note: Base and Registration Testcase classes are in one package and Registration is in another package.

**Below is my code:**
```

**Base Class**

```
package testcases;
import org.testng.annotations.BeforeTest;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxProfile;
import org.openqa.selenium.firefox.internal.ProfilesIni;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.WebDriverWait;
import org.testng.annotations.AfterTest;

public class Base {

    public WebDriver driver;
    public WebDriverWait wait;

  @BeforeTest
  public void beforeTest() {
      ProfilesIni pro = new ProfilesIni();
      FirefoxProfile ffProfile = pro.getProfile("vishvesh");
      ffProfile.setAcceptUntrustedCertificates(true);
      ffProfile.setAssumeUntrustedCertificateIssuer(false);
      String base_url = "http://automationpractice.com/index.php";
      System.setProperty("webdriver.gecko.driver", "G:/Workplace/AutomationSetupFiles/Geckdriver/geckodriver.exe");
      driver = new FirefoxDriver();
      driver.get(base_url);       
  }

  @AfterTest
  public void afterTest() {
      driver.close();
  }
}
```

**Registration Class**

```
package pages;

import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;
import org.openqa.selenium.WebElement;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.FindBy;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.PageFactory;
import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.ExpectedConditions;

import testcases.Base;

public class Registration extends Base{

    @FindBy(xpath="//*[@id='header']/div[2]//div[1]/a")
    WebElement SignIn;

    @FindBy(xpath="//input[@id='email_create']")
    WebElement Registration_Email;


    public Registration(WebDriver driver){
        this.driver=driver;
        PageFactory.initElements(driver, this);
    }

    public void ClickSignIn(){
        //wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOf(SignIn)).click();
        SignIn.click();
    }

    public void EnterEmail(String y){
        //wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOf(Registration_Email)).click();
        Registration_Email.click();
        Registration_Email.sendKeys(y);
    }


}
```

**Registration TestCase Class**

```
package testcases;

import org.testng.annotations.Test;

import pages.Registration;

public class Registatration_testcase extends Base{

  @Test
  public void f() {
      Registration regobj = new Registration(driver);
      regobj.ClickSignIn();
      regobj.EnterEmail("amdv1991@gmail.com");  
  }    
}
```

**Error What I get:**
FAILED CONFIGURATION:

```
@BeforeTest beforeTest
org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: 
Build info: version: 'unknown', revision: '8c03df6', time: '2017-03-02 09:32:39 -0800'
System info: host: 'LAPTOP-SCJ4OHK5', ip: '192.168.1.3', os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '1.8.0_131'
Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.firefox.FirefoxDriver
Capabilities [{moz:profile=C:\Users\VISHVE~1\AppData\Local\Temp\rust_mozprofile.XaA5YbSD8jeh, rotatable=false, timeouts={implicit=0, pageLoad=300000, script=30000}, pageLoadStrategy=normal, platform=ANY, specificationLevel=0, moz:accessibilityChecks=false, acceptInsecureCerts=false, browserVersion=53.0.3, platformVersion=10.0, moz:processID=7440, browserName=firefox, platformName=windows_nt}]
Session ID: 1ad0b6c1-bb5c-4306-afa6-b4e3dcb62ac1
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Unknown Source)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.W3CHttpResponseCodec.createException(W3CHttpResponseCodec.java:127)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.W3CHttpResponseCodec.decode(W3CHttpResponseCodec.java:93)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.http.W3CHttpResponseCodec.decode(W3CHttpResponseCodec.java:42)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.HttpCommandExecutor.execute(HttpCommandExecutor.java:163)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverCommandExecutor.execute(DriverCommandExecutor.java:82)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:604)
    at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.get(RemoteWebDriver.java:325)
    at testcases.Base.beforeTest(Base.java:30)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Unknown Source)
    at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:108)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeConfigurationMethod(Invoker.java:523)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeConfigurations(Invoker.java:224)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeConfigurations(Invoker.java:146)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.beforeRun(TestRunner.java:626)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:594)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:380)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:375)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:340)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:289)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:52)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:86)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1301)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1226)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuites(TestNG.java:1144)
    at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1115)
    at org.testng.remote.AbstractRemoteTestNG.run(AbstractRemoteTestNG.java:132)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.initAndRun(RemoteTestNG.java:230)
    at org.testng.remote.RemoteTestNG.main(RemoteTestNG.java:76)
```

Comment: Hints: The exception is at `at testcases.Base.beforeTest(Base.java:30)` with the `get` function. Please check it again by using debugger, try to get "google.com" instead to check if it works

Comment: @Tuyen Nguyen, the script opens the website in the browser, But it is supposed to click on a link which does not happen some how..

Answer (score 0):

I have seemed to have resolved this issue, Looked like there was some compatibility issues. Now I am using the following configurations

- selenium 3.4
- Firefox browser v48
- geckodriver 17